# Titanium app compilation error with node-gyp

Tags: titanium, macos-catalina, node-gyp

I'm trying to compile a Titanium app (on iOS) with a new computer.
But when I launch the compilation, I'm facing an error I don't understand :

```
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node /Users/clement/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/clement/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.3.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node --module_name=node_ios_device --module_path=/Users/clement/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.3.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi'
```

I saw it could be because of the space in "Application Support" ?

I don't understand the problem. Could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your nodejs version to 10.x (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/) and install the CLI again: `npm install -g titanium appcelerator alloy` and run the build process again.

**05/2020 - Titanium SDK 9**: you can now use Node 12.x!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, it's working :)

But I have now an other compilation error :

- With SDK 7.4.0.GA : "Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports at least iOS 8.0"
- With SDK 8.0.2.GA to 8.2.1.GA : "Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports iOS Simulator 13.2.2"
- With SDK 8.3.1.GA : "[LiveView] TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

Maybe you know where this other problem comes from? :)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: did you start xcode before you ran the bulid process? It looks like that there are no simulators installed yet